# Can you use the Polyjuice Potion to look like a younger version of yourself?

Tags: harry-potter, polyjuice-potion

Say you pulled out your Hogwarts robe for your 20 year reunion and found a hair on it. If you used a hair from 10-20 years ago in the Polyjuice Potion would you be a younger version of yourself? Would the potion work at all?
Could this be a temporary youth potion?

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe (not accepted, for starters), but it's worth looking at [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/100709) on [What would happen if you used the hair of a metamorphmagus in Polyjuice potion?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/100612): _Polyjuice clearly copies the current appearance of a person - for example, fake Moody copied the injuries, including the missing eye, of a real one. Haircuts are copied as-is (despite hair growing in all wizards as a dynamic thing). Harry's scar was copied in Battle of Seven Potters._